# Hyperlink control not showing within ContentTemplate in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<ContentTemplate>
        <div class="detail_purchase_button">

            <a class="commandbutton" href='/Courses?RestoreFilters=1'>Return to Catalog</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%# linkAddToCart %>

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

string url = "/Cart?AddItem={0}", DataItemID;
    linkAddToCart = new HyperLink();
    linkAddToCart.CssClass = "commandbutton";
    linkAddToCart.NavigateUrl = url;
    linkAddToCart.Text = "Add To Cart";
```

The button within the anchor tag shows up on the page. However, the Hyperlink button does not appear at all.
The second block of code is running in the Page_Load event (I will put it in a method after I get it to work) and is referencing a public Hyperlink field.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is hard to guess here. Please write small & concise code and test it at your side or post here if any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the hyperlink control via markup in the presentation file.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkAddToCart" runat="server" />
```

Place it where you need it to be. You can still reference its properties in your codebehind.

```
lnkAddToCart.CssClass = "commandbutton";
lnkAddToCart.NavigateUrl = url;
// etc.
```

If you were to define the control dynamically instead, you would need to add it to the appropriate container, such as a panel or placeholder

```
<asp:Panel id="theContainer" runat="server" /> or 
<asp:PlaceHolder id="theContainer" runat="server" />
```

...

```
// define the HyperLink as in your original code snippet 
theContainer.Controls.Add(lnkAddToCart);
```

However, unless you absolutely need to dynamically *create* the control, adding it to the the ASPX at design time is best. You can always set `Visible="false"` (to the markup, `.Visible = false;` in code) if it does not need to be displayed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit vague but I am trying to answer based on what I understand out of it. Please ignore if I misunderstood your question.

It is not possible to add an hyperlink like this. First put a placeholder(i.e. panel) within the contenttemplate and then add the hyperlink into the placeholder from code behind.

```
        <a class="commandbutton" href='/Courses?RestoreFilters=1'>Return to Catalog</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Panel id="pnlLink" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

And then in the code behind

```
string url = "/Cart?AddItem={0}", DataItemID;
linkAddToCart = new HyperLink();
linkAddToCart.CssClass = "commandbutton";
linkAddToCart.NavigateUrl = url;
linkAddToCart.Text = "Add To Cart";
pnlLink.Controls.Add(linkAddToCart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an ID to the `linkAddToCart` control that you create dynamically. Your code does not define an ID for it. With that being said, I would recommend doing this the way Anthony suggested. I don't see the need to do this kind of thing. If you want to have some logic for making appear in certain cases, just define it in your markup with `Visible="false"` and make it visible when you need to.